# Python - unexpected token '<newline>'<dedent>'

Tags: python, django

I've just made a function but I keep getting these two errors & I'm not too sure what the issue is -

```
unexpected token '<newline>'Python(parser-16)
unexpected token '<dedent>'Python(parser-16)
```

Here's the def code -

```
def get_user_membership(request):
    user_membership_qs = UserMembership.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    if user_membership_qs.exists():

        return user_membership_qs.first()

    return None
```

Comment: include the errors in your post with full traceback.

Answer (score -1):

I've got these errors too.
Check out if you are inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation.
After fixing the indentation, the code runs successfully.